# Display Payment methods in dropdown in magento admin grid

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I want to show all payment methods in a dropdown in admin grid in magento.I wish to display similar like that in the below picture.

[image]

Hoping for immediate response

Comment: how you have define offline payment method?

Comment: https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids

Answer (score 2):

Magento does `not have any flag to define  a payment is offline`.

In magento different  `payment modules are  made  in different process & logic`that why you `cannot check a payment module is offline or online`.

For just getting   `payment module list you can try @marius answer`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a column like this:

```
 $options = Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentMethodList(true, false, false);
 $this->addColumn('payment',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('payment')->__('Payment Method'),
            'width' => '60px',
            'index' => 'payment', //this can be different
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => $options,
    ));
```

Not sure if I got the parameters right for the `getPaymentMethodList`.
You can [take a look](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php#L199) here and see what each parameter means.

Comment: Cannot find any output in the grid

Comment: You mean you don't see the column in the grid? If so, can you post the full code from `_prepareColumns` method from your grid?

Comment: I can see the grid but not able to add dropdown in the grid for the payment methods